# Como mandar um array com ngmodel

Tags: array, angular, django

Estou refazendo um projeto agora em angular, e para pegar um array do form eu usava getlist e prod[] e qtd[] dentro da tag form, agora em angular se usa ngmodel e não o form em si, como posso pegar esses dados e mandar no back em forma de array, pelo ngModel?

```
<div>
<div class="row justify-content-around col-md-12">
<select class="form-control col-md-5 produtos" name="prod[]">
<option value="1">TST-01 - </option>
<option value="2">TST-02 - </option>
<option value="3">TST-02 - Teste-02</option>
</select>
<div class="col-md-7">
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
<input class="form-control col-md-2 mt-1 quantidade" min="0" max="999" type="number" name="qtd[]" placeholder=" Qtd">
<br>
</div>
```

ngModel

```
produto = { produto_desc: '', codigo: "", tipo: "", valoruni: "", valoruniDol: "", quantidade: 0, qtdvalorTot: 0, Compvalortot: '', CompvalortotDol: '', prod: [], qtd: [] };
```

Comment: Você quer pegar os dados selecionados dentro do option?

Comment: Ou você quer mandar do back e pegar no select? usando ngModel?

Comment: Esses inputs que eu coloco são dinamicos, quando o cara clicka no botão aparece outro select pra ele selecionar outro produto e quantidade, queria juntar isso em um array ou dois um de produtos e outro de quantidades e mandar para o back, usando ngModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando se esta fazendo um formulário em angular, maneira mais comum de capturar esses dados e colocar os valores obtido pelo formulário em um objeto, caso você queira armazenar múltiplos valores, dentro de uma propriedade qualquer do objeto você pode colocar um array, segue o exemplo de como ficaria seu formulário com o objeto.

**Na View**

```
<div>
<div class="row justify-content-around col-md-12">
<select class="form-control col-md-5 produtos" [(ngModel)]="form.produto_selecionado">
<option value="{{prod.id}}" *ngFor="let prod of form.produtos">{{prod.nome_produto}}</option>
</select>
<div class="col-md-7">
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
<input class="form-control col-md-2 mt-1 quantidade" min="0" max="999" type="number" [(ngModel)]="form.qtde_produto" placeholder=" Qtd">
<br>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button" (click)="enviar(form)"></button>
```

**Na Controller**

```
export class Produtos implements OnInit {
    form: any = {};
    constructor() {
        this.form.qtde = 1;
        this.form.produtos = [
            {
                id: 1,
                nome_produto: 'produto 1'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                nome_produto: 'produto 2'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                nome_produto: 'produto 3'
            },
        ];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
    enviar(produto) {
        console.log(produto);
    }
}
```

Ao final quando clicar no botão para enviar você vai ter o objeto do formulário preenchido para tratar como quiser. Abracos